# Clearing expired cache entries from disk cache on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app which uses disk cache for the now default Russian-doll caching. I have no trouble with invalidating the cache and my cache strategy is working to my requirements, however I have to find a proper way to delete the expired entries from the disk. As documented the disk cache keeps on growing until it is either cleared or the disk is full.

I'm aware that I can do `rake tmp:cache:clear` but that deletes the entire cache, not just stale items! I'm looking for a better way which will preserve fresh entries and delete from the disk only stale cached entries. I'm already using a shell script to delete entries that have not been accessed in the last day but this does not guarantee I'm deleting only stale entries and preserving all fresh entries.

I am aware I can switch to memcached or redis, but I prefer not to, as disk cache is doing a fine job without the overhead of resources and supporting yet another server (server in terms of a server process, not actual hardware/virtual-machine).

How do you clear stale cache entries when using disk cache? Is there a better way then using the files' atime/mtime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to documentation, you might use #cleanup
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/FileStore.html#method-i-cleanup

You could, for example, schedule a cron job to run it periodically on your hosts
./script/rails runner -e production 'Rails.cache.cleanup'

Comment: It's odd that they said `Preemptively` in the documentation, does that mean it should run by itself?